# Non Mass assignable field in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, mass-assignment, button-to

Iam kinda stuck at this problem. Trying to update a non mass-assignable attribute in the job model from an admin view. I need a button which trigger an action method in the admin controller which just changes job's isactive value to true.

In admin controller:

```
     def approve
    @job.update_attribute(:isactive = true)
    if @job.save
      redirect_to(:action => :show)
      flash[:notice] = "Job Approved"
    else
      render 'show'
    end
  end
```

In jobs/1 view

```
<div style="text-align:center;" class="widget">
<%= form_for(@job, :url => url_for(:controller => 'admin', :action => 'approve'), :html => {:id => "contact_form", :class => "g-form"}) do |f| %>

<%= button_tag( :class => "g-btn type_default") do %>
<i class="icon-share-alt icon-white"></i>Approve this job 
<% end %>
 <% end %>      
<% end %>
```

No matter what i do this form gets submitted to the job update action and show job successfully updated rather than the notice "Job approved" from the approve action in admin.

I have added the following route as well. but not sure what iam doing wrong. I need a simple button (ideally a block because of the styling req) which sets job's isactive field to true.

```
match "jobs/:id", :via=>:post, :controller=>"admin", :action=>"approve"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mass assignment was designed to protect precisely against what you're trying to do here so ideally speaking, you should add it to a whitelist (`attr_accessible`) if you need to modify it.

However, there are a few issues with your controller action that will need to be addressed even if you get the `isactive` attribute whitelisted.

`@job.update_attribute(:isactive = true)` is not valid. `update_attribute` does not handle assignments, the correct syntax is `update_attribute(attribute, value)` so it should be:

```
@job.update_attribute(:isactive, true)
```

Also, the `update_attribute` method calls save on the passed object. Calling `@job.save` after `update_attribute` (provided there is no other code assigning attributes) is redundant.

A better way to write this method would be:

```
def approve
  if @job.update_attribute(:isactive, true)
    redirect_to(:action => :show)
    flash[:notice] = "Job Approved"
  else
    render 'show'
  end
end
```

However, if you cannot modify the model and are not worried about callbacks or validation, you can update the database column directly with `update_column` (or `update_columns` in Rails 4):

```
def approve
  if @job.update_column(:isactive, true)
    redirect_to(:action => :show)
    flash[:notice] = "Job Approved"
  else
    render 'show'
  end
end
```